# The right position of "both"

Tags: word-order, determiners

I wrote this sentence:

> Spelling words in English is challenging for both native speakers and language learners.

I feel it is correct, but I am little confused about using "both", could the sentence be:

> Spelling words in English is challenging both for the native speakers and the language learners.

What is the normal position of "both"?

Comment: Both positions sound very natural. They both work just as well. (Also, you should say "I wrote this sentence", instead of "I made this sentence".)

Comment: Did you intend to use *the* in only one of the two sentences?

Comment: Rather than worry about its position,  I would leave out "both" unless there is a specific reason in context. It is implied with two items joined by "and".  But if you insist either position is fine. And you don't need "the" as those nouns are groups of people.

Comment: @user3169 Thank you, I think you can guess the context. This matter that the spelling is challenging for language learners is not surprising, but that it is difficult for the native speakers is a bit surprising. Then I used "both" to emphasize this. Is it a proper usage of "both"?

Comment: For emphasis it is OK to use *both*. In that case, I would go with  *challenging both* since you want to emphasize the challenge.

Comment: @snailboat: I specifically added <strike>made</strike> when I corrected the text, because this OP made the same error before (which I *didn't* correct), ***and*** I noted that he'd been here for almost 2 hours after Jacob suggested the change. Why do you think the strikethrough should be removed?

Comment: It doesn't help anything.  The OP can see the revision history fine without it.  And it only serves as a distraction for other users who read this question in the future.  We want to minimize that sort of thing, since our goal is to create a repository of helpful questions and answers for people coming in from Google.  (If you'd like to discuss this further, why not start a discussion on Meta.ELL and see what everyone else thinks?  I'm fairly certain we had this discussion in comments before, maybe in 2013, but I'm too lazy to find it...)

Comment: @snailboat: I seem to recall we may not have always seen eye to eye on everything here (though I know you're an excellent thinker, and wise in the ways of "TEFL"). So maybe we *have* hit this very issue before (or maybe it was summat else! :) As of right now, I'm inclined to defend such use of "persistent, visible" strikethrough, on the grounds that if multiple users (or even, *single* users repeatedly, in some cases) make a mistake, it's worth flagging it up to *future* visitors to create/reinforce a sense of what's "right" in a relatively non-distracting fashion. Meta may beckon tomorrow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these figures from Google Books...

> [*both for A and B*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20both%20you%20and%20me%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22both%20for%20a%20and%20b%22) - 8 results
>    [*both for A and for B*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20both%20you%20and%20me%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22both%20for%20a%20and%20for%20b%22) - 7 results
>    [*for both A and B*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20both%20you%20and%20me%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22for%20both%20a%20and%20b%22) - About 495 results

In most cases we try to put ***both*** as near as possible to the two things being referenced. If you allow a preposition like ***for*** to intervene unnecessarily, you force the reader/listener to (momentarily) suspend parsing until the *next* word, since ***both*** could feasibly apply to ***for***...

> *Some Greeks are **both for** and **against** austerity - they simply don't know which way to turn.*

Answer (score 0):

You should see the construction in this way:

- It is a challenge for both: (for) natives and non-natives.

Comment: Then I can't say "both for"? If yes, then how should I see that?

Comment: I was meant as a help. If it does not help you simply forget it.